# Сортировка матрицы по возрастанию

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка, матрицы

Дан массив 100 на 100, который хаотично заполнен координатами. Надо отсортировать его так, что бы самая маленькая координата была в начале матрицы, а самая большая в конце.

То есть из:

```
(0,0) (2,0) (2,2)
(2,1) (0,2) (1,0)
(0,1) (1,2) (1,1)
```

Надо получить:

```
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2)
(1,0) (1,1) (1,2) 
(2,0) (2,1) (2,2)
```

```
public class Main {
    public static class main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
    Point[][] point = new Point[100][100];
    public Main() {
        for (int i = 0; i < point.length; i++) for (int j = 0; j < point[i].length; j++)
            point[i][j] = new Point((int)(Math.random()*100),(int)(Math.random()*100));
        sort(point);
        for (int i = 0; i < point.length; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < point[i].length; j++) 
                System.out.print(point[i][j].x+";"+point[i][j].y);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void sort (Point[][] point) {
         //sort code
    }
}
```

Comment: Что означает самая маленькая координата и как вообще вы сравниваете пары чисел?

Comment: самая маленькая координата - это координата с самыми маленькими значениями Х и У в списке.

Comment: Мне надо сделать так, что бы в каждой строке массива числа лежали по возрастанию

Comment: строки в матрице должны быть отсортированы по Х, а столбики по У

Comment: а что из себя представляет элемент? Объект с двумя double?

Comment: Объект класса Point

Comment: В вашем примере точки все точки однозначно соответствуют целым координатам, лишних и недостающих нет, т.е. просто вторая матрица перемешана. Так будет всегда?

Answer (score 3):

Перегоняете двумерный массив в одномерный (размером 100 х 100), сортируете одномерный по нужному вам критерию, перегоняете одномерный обратно в двумерный

```
public static void sort(Point[][] point) {
    Point[] tmp = new Point[point.length * point[0].length];
    int k = 0;
    for (Point[] row : point)
        for (Point p : row)
            tmp[k++] = p;

    Arrays.sort(tmp, (o1, o2) -> o1.x == o2.x ? o1.y - o2.y : o1.x - o2.x);

    k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < point.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < point[i].length; j++)
            point[i][j] = tmp[k++];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если допускается создание дополнительного *одномерного* массива, в котором собственно и выполняется сортировка, с последующим "переписыванием" входной  матрицы отсортированными значениями, это можно сделать следующим образом (при помощи Stream API)

```java
public static void sort(Point[][] arr) {
    Point[] sorted = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Point::getX)
            .thenComparing(Point::getY)
        )
        .toArray(Point[]::new);
    for (int i = 0, cols = arr[0].length, n = arr.length * cols; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i / cols][i % cols] = sorted[i];
    }
}
```

Однако для достаточно больших массивов использование дополнительного массива того же размера может быть нежелательным, и тогда лучше использовать собственную реализацию *быстрой сортировки* (см. [Quicksort Algorithm Implementation in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-quicksort)) с поправкой на сортировку двумерного массива, т.е. придётся дополнительно определить несколько методов для конвертации одномерного индекса в позицию в матрице и для перестановки элементов в матрице.

```java
public static <T> void quickSort(T arr[][], Comparator<T> cmp) {
    quickSort(arr, 0, arr.length * arr[0].length - 1, cmp);
}

public static <T> void quickSort(T arr[][], int begin, int end, Comparator<T> cmp) {
    if (begin < end) {
        int partitionIndex = partition(arr, begin, end, cmp);

        quickSort(arr, begin, partitionIndex - 1, cmp);
        quickSort(arr, partitionIndex + 1, end, cmp);
    }
}

private static <T> int partition(T arr[][], int begin, int end, Comparator<T> cmp) {
    T pivot = getAt(arr, end);
    int i = begin - 1;

    for (int j = begin; j < end; j++) {
        T curr = getAt(arr, j);
        if (cmp.compare(curr, pivot) <= 0) {
            swap(arr, ++i, j);
        }
    }
    swap(arr, ++i, end);

    return i;
}

private static <T> T getAt(T[][] arr, int i) {
    return arr[i / arr[0].length][i % arr[0].length];
}

private static <T> void swap(T[][] arr, int i, int j) {
    T temp = getAt(arr, i);
    int cols = arr[0].length;
    arr[i / cols][i % cols] = arr[j / cols][j % cols];
    arr[j / cols][j % cols] = temp;
}
```

---

Тест для реализации `quickSort` (c использованием Lombok):

```java
@Data
@Accessors(fluent = true) // убрать префиксы get в геттерах
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Point {
    private final int x, y;
}

// record Point(int x, int y) {} // аналогично в Java 16+
```

```java
// public static void main(String ... args) {
Point[][] points = {
    {new Point(9, 2), new Point(6, 7), new Point(3, 8), new Point(3, 4)},
    {new Point(1, 1), new Point(6, 5), new Point(8, 4), new Point(2, 2)},
    {new Point(5, 9), new Point(3, 1), new Point(2, 6), new Point(1, 5)}
};

quickSort(points, Comparator.comparingInt(Point::x).thenComparingInt(Point::y));
for (Point[] p : points) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p));
}
// }
```

Результат:

```
[Point(x=1, y=1), Point(x=1, y=5), Point(x=2, y=2), Point(x=2, y=6)]
[Point(x=3, y=1), Point(x=3, y=4), Point(x=3, y=8), Point(x=5, y=9)]
[Point(x=6, y=5), Point(x=6, y=7), Point(x=8, y=4), Point(x=9, y=2)]
```